# Is this code assigning to window.location vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: javascript, xss

Can any one tell me whether this code is vulnerable or not?. If it is please give some XSS example so I can understand.

Code Page URL:

```
https://myweb.com/auth?redirect_uri=https://otherurl.com/sdfdsf/sdfsdf
```

**Is this code vulnerable to XSS?**

```html
<a id="forgotPassword">forgotPassword</a>

<script>
//Jquery Code

$('#forgotPassword').click(function(){
 var redirectUri='https://otherurl.com/sdfdsf/sdfsdf',URLMatch=redirectUri.match(/^(.*?)(.com|.ca)/);
  if(URLMatch){
   window.location=URLMatch[0]+"/forgotPassword";
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you changed the actual code  and you changed the most relevant part. `redirectUri` is assigned from user input (window.location maybe?) in the real code I guess, and in that case this is indeed vulnerable to dom xss. (Though it would probably not be straightforward to exploit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this code is automatically generated so that the value of `redirectUri` is read from the query parameter `redirect_uri` from the page URL `https://myweb.com/auth?redirect_uri=...` **without encoding or escaping and your regular expression stays that way** (i.e. must match either `.com` or `.ca`) then you're potentially vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Here's a threat model:

A user go to `https://myweb.com/auth?redirect_uri=javascript:alert(42)//.com`

Then at `https://myweb.com/auth` a script extracts the `redirect_uri` parameter from the URL and feeds it into an **insecure** Mustache template. e.g.

```js
const  mustache = require("mustache");

const template = `
$('#forgotPassword').click(function(){
 var redirectUri='{{{url}}}',URLMatch=redirectUri.match(/^(.*?)(.com|.ca)/);
  if(URLMatch){
   window.location=URLMatch[0]+"/forgotPassword";
  }
});
`;

const jquery_code = mustache.render(template, {
  url: new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('redirect_uri')
});
```

This is what the `jquery_code` variable contains:

```js
$('#forgotPassword').click(function(){
 var redirectUri='javascript:alert(42)//.com',URLMatch=redirectUri.match(/^(.*?)(.com|.ca)/);
  if(URLMatch){
   window.location=URLMatch[0]+"/forgotPassword";
  }
});
```

Let's see what that does if injected into the page: *(I have instead decided to log into the console, what the script will assign to `window.location`. Copy/paste and run into your console yourself to see what happens.)*

```js
$('#forgotPassword').click(function(){
 var redirectUri='javascript:alert(42)//.com',URLMatch=redirectUri.match(/^(.*?)(.com|.ca)/);
  if(URLMatch){
   // window.location=URLMatch[0]+"/forgotPassword";
   console.log(
     `window.location="${URLMatch[0]+"/forgotPassword"}";`
   )
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="forgotPassword">forgotPassword</a>
```

---

**What happened?**

1. The `{{{ }}}` Mustache notation opts you out of encoding/escaping. i.e. you consume the value as is.
2. You have allowed a JavaScript url because of your regex. Check for *must begin with `https` or `http`* instead.